# Regex to allow only number and the letter X

Tags: javascript, regex, input

Hi I need a regex to allow only numbers and the letter "x"... I'm trying something like this

```
target.value = target.value.replace(/[^x]\D/g, "")
```

But it deletes what's inputed already and it's still allowing special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `\d` inside `[]`. Otherwise you're removing any not-x followed by not-digit.

```js
s = "abc123xyz";
console.log(s.replace(/[^x\d]/g, ''));
```